# Tikz/pgfplots : have same axes area size

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to specify *axes size* in latex units, *not figure size* for tikz plots.
I want to make a table of plots with the same size of axes are, but
possibly different size of the entire figure, due to different size of tick labels.

E.g. doing something like this (files generated by matplotlib2tikz)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[!htb]
        \setlength\figurewidth{0.3\textwidth}
        \setlength\figureheight{1\figurewidth}
        \begin{tabular}[b]{r}
            \input{images/synth/b0_00.tex} \\
            \input{images/synth/b1_00.tex} \\
            \input{images/synth/b2_00.tex} \\
            \input{images/synth/s_00.tex} 
        \end{tabular}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

produces this

[image: ugly unaligned graphs]

but I would like the left and the right spines to be aligned.

Comment: In `pgfplots` you want [`groupplots`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf#section.5.8).

Comment: In `matplotlib` use [`subplot`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html).

Comment: Any updates here? Have you tried groupplots or subplots?

Comment: @Bobyandbob phew, that was a long time ago. I did try (both simultaneously - this is the way to go) and succeeded. But I don't really remember the gory details -  I see a lot of sed postprocessing in my code as well as some options in extra tikz options for axes, which might or might not be related to the issue in this particular question.  Anyway If Henri Menke would have made an answer out of those two comments I would have gladly accepted it.

Comment: @HenriMenke would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Actually no.  I think the question is not answerable and also not useful to other readers.  I vote to close.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't mind FYI. I also don't mind deleting it with my own bare hands if you both agree.